# Is there any solution for scrolling customView smoothly in ViewPager2 which does not scroll smoothly initially

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2, android-viewpager2

I get a List of Item from a backend API and show the item of the list in Viewpager horizontally. List is fetched and showed in ViewPager successfully. But the problem is,  initially sliding is not smooth and after sometimes, it starts sliding smoothly. How to smoother the sliding from the very beginning

I use Retrofit and rxjava for fetching list from the server. I also use LiveData to observe the change of viewModel's variable in Fragment

`TestimonialService.kt`

```
@GET(Constants.API_TESTIMONIAL)
fun getAllTestimonial(): Flowable<Response<TestimonialResponse>>
```

`WelcomeViewModel.kt`

```
val uiState: MutableLiveData<Event<UiState<TestimonialResponse>>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getAllTestimonial() {
    compositeDisposable += testimonialService.getAllTestimonial()
        .performOnBackgroundOutputOnMain()
        .doOnSubscribe { uiState.value = Event(loading(true)) }
        .doOnTerminate { uiState.value = Event(loading(false)) }
        .subscribe({
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                uiState.value = Event(success(it.body()!!)!!)
            } else {
                uiState.value = Event(alert(it.code().toString()))
            }
        }, {
            uiState.value = Event(failure(it))
        })
}
```

`TestimonialAdapter.kt`

```
class TestimonialAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<TestimonialViewHolder>() {

    var testimonialList: List<Testimonial>? = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TestimonialViewHolder {
        val view = ItemTestimonialBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return TestimonialViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TestimonialViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(testimonialList?.get(position)!!)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = testimonialList?.size ?: 0

    fun notifyChanged(testimonialList: ArrayList<Testimonial>) {
        this.testimonialList = testimonialList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

`TestimonialViewHolder.kt`

```
class TestimonialViewHolder(private val bindingView: ItemTestimonialBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bindingView.root) {

    fun bind(testimonial: Testimonial) {
        bindingView.testimonial = testimonial
    }

}
```

`item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="com.caretutors.api.serviceModel.testimonials.Testimonial"/>
        <variable name="testimonial" type="Testimonial" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_22sdp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/client_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:image="@{testimonial.photo}"
                    tools:src="@drawable/ic_round_avatar" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@{testimonial.name}"
                        tools:text="@string/john_doe"
                        android:textColor="@color/black_85_percent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp_text_size"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semi_bold"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/designation_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@{testimonial.designation}"
                        tools:text="@string/web_developer"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_ash"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp_text_size" />

                    <ScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:fillViewport="true">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/comment_text_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:text="@{testimonial.comment}"
                            tools:text="@string/short_description"
                            android:textColor="@color/black_50_percent"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/eleven_sp_text_size" />

                    </ScrollView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

`fragment.welcome.xml`

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/testimonial_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_110sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

`WelcomeFragment.kt`

```
override fun initWidget() {
    with(testimonial_view_pager) {
        adapter = testimonialAdapter
        offscreenPageLimit = 1
        setPageTransformer(CustomPageTransformer(context!!, R.dimen.testimonial_viewpager_visible_portion_of_next_item, R.dimen.testimonial_viewpager_current_item_horizontal_margin))
        addItemDecoration(CustomHorizontalMarginItemDecorator(context, R.dimen.testimonial_viewpager_current_item_horizontal_margin))
    }
}

override fun observeLiveData() {
    with(viewModel) {
        getAllTestimonial()

        uiState.observe(this@WelcomeFragment, Observer {
            it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { state ->
                when (state) {

                    is Progress -> {
                        with(shimmer_view_container) {
                            if (state.isLoading) {
                                startShimmer()
                            } else {
                                stopShimmer()
                                visibilityGone()
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    is Success -> {
                        val testimonialList = state.successInfo.data as ArrayList<Testimonial>
                        testimonialAdapter.notifyChanged(testimonialList)

                        AutoSlider(testimonial_view_pager, testimonialList.size).startAutoSlider()
                    }

                    is Alert -> context?.showToast(state.alert)

                    is Failure -> {
                        if (state.throwable is IOException) {
                            context?.showToast("Internet Connection Failed")
                        } else {
                            context?.showToast("Json Parsing Error")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

`AutoSlider.kt`

```
class AutoSlider(private val viewPager: ViewPager2, private val totalItem: Int) {

private var runnable: Runnable? = null
private val handler = Handler()

init {
    runnable = Runnable {
        var position = viewPager.currentItem
        position += 1
        if (position >= totalItem) position = 0

        viewPager.currentItem = position
    }
}

fun startAutoSlider() {
    val swipeTimer = Timer()

    swipeTimer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            handler.post(runnable)
        }
    }, 3000, 3000)
}
```

}

Initially scrolling is not smooth. But after sometimes, it starts scrolling smoothly

Comment: why you delay the runnable?

Comment: There may be a problem in the CustomPageTransformer()

Answer (score 0):

```
class AutoSlider(private val viewPager: ViewPager2) {

    private var runnable: Runnable? = null
    private val handler = Handler()

    fun startAutoSlider(totalItem: Int) {
        runnable = Runnable {
            var position = viewPager.currentItem
            position += 1
            if (position >= totalItem) position = 0

            viewPager.currentItem = position
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000)//remove this line
        }

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000)
    }
```

you postdelay twice, just remove this line I mentioned

Comment: If I remove the line you mentioned, unfortunately, the silder doesn't move. It just moves once when the fragment first launch

Comment: I updated AutoSlider class. But still same problem. Please check the Updated AutoSlider class